# JSP - loop through table by key value

Tags: java, jsp, loops

I have a picture attached with pretty much all the information.  To add to it.  The table data is stored within a java bean within an ArrayList (Each record is one bean).

I would like my application to be able to recognize that I am in CYCLE_ID *n* and have all the runs displayed in a table (see Desired Results), and for each CYCLE_ID the same thing.

I am open to making changes in the background java class (not shown), or within the jsp.

[image]

```
<div id="activeQueue">
<h2>Active Modeling Queue for <bean:write name="userBean" property="uid" />   </h2>
<c:forEach items="${activeQueueList}" var="currentQueue">
  <p>Queue {<c:out value="${currentQueue.modelQueueID}" />} - <c:out value="${currentQueue.PROJECTION_PROJECT_NME}" /></p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Start Time </th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${currentQueue.modelQueueDes}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${currentQueue.ROW_CREATE_TSP}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${currentQueue.STATUS_DES}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First prepare a `Map` using CYCLE_ID as key and the `Queue List` as the value. Assuming the bean class is `ActiveQueue` you can do the following

```
    Map<Integer, ActiveQueue> data = new HashMap<Integer, ActiveQueue>();
    for(ActiveQueue queue : activeQueueList) {
        if(!data.containsKey(queue.CYCLE_ID)) {
            data.put(queue.CYCLE_ID, new ArrayList<ActiveQueue>);                
        } 

        data.get(queue.CYCLE_ID).add(queue);
    }
```

Now you can use two nested loops in jsp. The outer loop iterates over the `Map data` and the inner loop iterates over the corresponding `Map.entry values`. Like following

```
    <div id="activeQueue">
        <h2>Active Modeling Queue for <bean:write name="userBean" property="uid" /></h2>
        <c:forEach items="${data}" var="entry">
            <p>Queue {<c:out value="${entry.key}" />} - <c:out value="${entry.value[0].PROJECTION_PROJECT_NME}" /></p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Start Time </th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items=${entry.value} var="currentQueue">
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${currentQueue.modelQueueDes}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${currentQueue.ROW_CREATE_TSP}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${currentQueue.STATUS_DES}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
         </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a `List<Run>` and iterating on it, you should have a `List<Cycle>`, where each Cycle contains a `List<Run>`.

Grouping the original flat list of Runs by Cycle is easy with a Map storing the ID of the cycles as keys, and the corresponding cycle as value:

- you iterate over the runs
- for each run, you fetch the corresponding cycle by ID in the map. If it's not there yet, you create it and store it in the map
- you add the run in the cycle

Ath the end, the keySet() of the map contains all the cycles, and each cycle contains all its runs.

Then use two nested foreach loops in the JSP.